# An immersed submanifold is locally embedded

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

We know

> Let M be a smooth manifold with or without boundary,$S\subset M$ be an
> immersed submanifold.
>
> for each p exist a neighborhood $U$ **in $S$** that is embedded
> submanifold.

Now an example to illustrate neighborhood should be $U$ of **$S$** not open subset $V$ of M, in  Lee's smooth manifold book page 111.

[image]

the question is Why this curve is not topological embedding globally? And choosing neighborhood  $V$ in $M$ fails around $p$ to make $V\bigcap S$ embedded?

Comment: The neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ in the figure above is open in $S$  but fail to open in $\iota(S) \subseteq M$ with subspace topology. So $\iota$, not a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @Si Kucing , thanks,nice comment. $U$ is locally embedded submanifold since we can ignore the rest part of curve,correct?

Comment: Yes. The tail is not a part of the curve anymore, so now the restricted inclusion map is a topological embedding.